# randomly changing the colour of foreground and background in c#

Tags: c#, random, colors, console-application

I have a code here that randomly chooses a string from an array, then uses that corresponding string to change the color of the background. The same is done for the foreground, but there is a lot of code, and if i wanted to add any more colors, it would be quite time consuming.
Any tips?

Here is the code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Input your name: ");
            string yourName = Console.ReadLine();
            while (true)
                {
                string[] colours = new string[5] {"red" , "white", "yellow" , "magenta" , "blue" };
                int backColour = random.Next(0,5);
                if (backColour == 0)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                }
                if (backColour == 1)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                }
                if (backColour == 2)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                }
                if (backColour == 3)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                }
                if (backColour == 4)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                }

                int frontColour = random.Next(0, 5);
                if (frontColour == 0)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                }
                if (frontColour == 1)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                }
                if (frontColour == 2)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                }
                if (frontColour == 3)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                }
                if (frontColour == 4)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                }


                Console.Write("All work and no pla`enter code here`y makes " + yourName + " a dull person! ");
                Console.Clear();
                }
        }
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: I would suggest Randomly select Red, Green, Blue component separately i.e 0 to 255 and compose them to make a color.

Comment: Just put the color-objects in an array and loop through the array, which each index has a different color. You can always add or delete colors in the array without changing the code of the loop.

Comment: fore and back color can be the same?

Comment: Just noticed - your `while` loop seems off since you will get a Disco mode with permanenty changing colors - your `Console.ReadLine()` should probably be inside of the `while` loop to make the loop halt and wait for further Input - and you should have some exit code to not have a endless loop.

Answer (score 3):

Choose the colors directly instead of `int -> string[] -> color`

```
ConsoleColor[] colours = { ConsoleColor.Red, 
                           ConsoleColor.White, 
                           ConsoleColor.Yellow, 
                           ConsoleColor.Magenta, 
                           ConsoleColor.Blue };
Console.BackgroundColor = colours[random.Next(0, colours.Length)];
Console.ForegroundColor = colours[random.Next(0, colours.Length)];
```

Comment: Would be wise to limit the code to not have the same `BackgroundColor` and `ForegroundColor` - would be kind of hard to read :)

Comment: @RandRandom that would change the logic of th OP - see my comment at the question

Comment: Yeah, missed your comments - great minds, think a like, I guess :)